# Continuous functions for countable dense subset in a separable metric space

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Suppose that $(X, d)$ is a separable metric space with countable dense subset $\widetilde{X}$, and Y a metric space. Let
$f : X \to Y$ and $g : X \to Y$ be continuous functions such that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in \widetilde{X}$. Show that
$f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

Here is my attempt:

Since $\forall{x} \in \widetilde{X}$, $f(x), g(x)$ are continuous and $f(x) = g(x)$, let $\{{x_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \widetilde{X}$, then $x_n \to x$ implies that $f(x_n)=g(x_n) \to g(x)=f(x)$, but since $\widetilde{X}$ is a countable dense subset of $X$, $x_n \subset \widetilde{X} \subset X$ and the limit points $x \in X$, so $\forall{x} \in X, f(x)=g(x)$.

I appreciate if any one can help me validate the proof or give me suggestions on it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof lacks accuracy. I can't see the final argument why $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in X$. I suggest the following.

Fix $x\in X$. Since $X$ is metric and $\widetilde{X}$ is dense, there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\in\widetilde{X}$ and $x_n\to x$. By continuity of $f$ and $g$, we have
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n)=g(x).$$
QED.

Remark: Some assumptions are redundant here and the following stronger theorem holds (but the proof is different):

If $f,g\colon X\rightarrow Y$ are continuous, $Y$ is Hausdorff, and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in \widetilde{X}$, where $\widetilde{X}$ is dense, then $f=g$.

Comment: Thanks for the final statement! We have not covered Hausdorff in our real analysis class but thanks for the remark.